# MPI in C primitive MPI_Allgather [SOLVED]

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to use this primitive, but I can't find a good solution.

In my example I have nProcesses and each ona has a vector c of k elements. I want that each process has all the elements of the other processes too and so each process has a new vector of k*k elements. This is what I did

```
int c[k];
int mtemp[k*k];
MPI_Allgather(&c[0],k,MPI_INT,&mtemp[0],k*(nProc-1),MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

In this way each process send k elements and receives k*(nProc-1) elements, but when I run, for each process I only have a mtemp of k*2 elements, their elements and the elements of process 0

Comment: Gather and scatter calls are confusing. The receive count in your case is how many elements come from any process, not from all together. Stated different: the send count and receive count are usually the same.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout hi, I tried using k in the receive count, but then when I run I get this error:   control_cb (pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_cb.c:206): assert (!closed) failed
HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (tools/demux/demux_poll.c:76): callback returned error status
HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:160): error waiting for event
 main (ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:325): process manager error waiting for completion

Comment: That error probably has nothing to do with the gather call. Print out the result of your gather first to see if it's correct.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout ok I fixed that error. The problem was that mtemp is k*nProc and not k*k